# aws configure creates userprofile folder and files

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to set the path other than %USERPROFILE% for aws configure?
I cannot explain why, but on Windows 10 after aws configure runs, it automatically creates the following path and files:

C:\Users\myusername\%**USERPROFILE**%\Documents.aws

Note the userprofile folder is **actually named that way**. It's not the windows environment folder.

Normally its supposed to create C:\users\myusername.aws etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, apart from `%USERPROFILE` there is no other way for aws configure

[aws cli configure code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/configure/configure.py#L122)

```py
    def _write_out_creds_file_values(self, new_values, profile_name):
        # The access_key/secret_key are now *always* written to the shared
        # credentials file (~/.aws/credentials), see aws/aws-cli#847.
        # post-conditions: ~/.aws/credentials will have the updated credential
        # file values and new_values will have the cred vars removed.
        credential_file_values = {}
```

[Where are configuration settings stored?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-where)

Home directory is referred to using the environment variables `%UserProfile%` in Windows and `$HOME` or `~` (tilde) in Unix-based systems.

But there is something more to it:

> As a general rule, any value that you can place in the credentials file can alternatively be placed in the config file. The other way isn't true: only a few settings can be placed in the credentials file.

So you can place credentials in `.aws/config` file,and for there is an environment variable named `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` you can pass and it will be written there. [Even though it is not recommended to place credentials in config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/file-location.html#file-location-config)